# What language and database is used for Tally ERP development?

Tags: tally

What programming language and database technology does Tally ERP use for development?

[Link to Tally's website](https://tallysolutions.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tally ERP is built with a programming language developed specifically for Tally called TDL (Tally Definition Language), [a high-level object-oriented language.](https://help.tallysolutions.com/article/DeveloperReference/td9/introduction.htm)

Since the language is proprietary, I think you'll have a hard time finding much public information on the language outside of Tally-specific courses or paying for access as a developer.

You can view Tally's Help section on their website [here](https://help.tallysolutions.com).

Answer (score -1):

Tally and its Tally Definition Language are developed with **C++**

Comment: Can you please provide any source of this information?